# sprintf_s template base overload not working

Tags: c++, templates, std

VS2010. I am converting sprintf stmts into sprintf_s. I noticed there are two implementations, from intellisense:

```
int sprintf_s<_Size>(char (&_Dest)[_Size], const char *_Format, ...)
int sprintf_s(char * _DestBuf, size_t _SizeInBytes, const char *_Format, ...)
```

So how come the compiler wont accept:

```
void Test(char buf[])
{ 
   sprintf_s<10>(buf, "%s", "test");
}
```

Comment: *"the compiler wont accept"* - what error message do you get?

Comment: Inside `Test()`, the parameter `buf` is not an array but a _pointer_ (`void Test(char buf[])` is actually the same as `void Test(char *buf)`), so you can't use the template version. You can use the non-template `sprintf_s(buf, 10, "%s", "test");` but that `10` looks a bit "magic"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759.aspx) shows you need to define one or two macros to enable these template overloads. I do not think these are made to be used directly, rather they serve the purpose of checking the size of the static buffer at compile time through the C++ template instead of a runtime check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the templated version, the idea is that the compiler can deduce the _Size template parameter from the parameters you pass to sprintf_s, not that you specify it.

So basically, you use it like this:

```
char dest[10];
sprintf_s(dest, "Format %s string", "blah");
```

Comment: That was my conclusion also. rubevnb: "there are not meant to be use directly" is what I was looking for. Txs.